# No property for controller when sending param to controller from view

Tags: grails

I am trying to send a param through a link, but I get the error

```
No such property: id for class: com.me.MyController
```

This is the function that I am trying to call in my controller

```
def myFunction(id){
    render(view:'index')
}
```

And this is the link in my view that I am trying to use to link to the action

```
<g:link controller="MyController" action="myFunction" params="[id:'1']">My Link</g:link>
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `id` in the function signature needs a type. For example...

```
def myFunction(String id){
    render(view:'index')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out reference to [params](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Controllers/params.html)

and instead try:

```
def myFunction(){
     print params.id
     render(view:'index')
}
```